# Loss convergence in deep learning

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, optimization

I have seen in many machine learning papers and talks, people refer to loss convergence. I assume they refer to loss on development set, but, what I am not sure about is that if they mean when they run the training code, at each epoch of the training procedure the loss drops, Or they mean if they run their training code several times, it always ends up at the same loss value on the development set?

I think given the complexity of the objective functions (in many cases) it is very unlikely to end up with the same loss every time training is done. So perhaps they mean it drops between each consecutive epochs. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct. The usual way to train a neural network is to train the same network on several epochs.

The training stops when a certain number of epochs is attained or when an *early stopping* criterion is attained: when the loss on the **validation set** stops decreasing.

Comment: What about the loss across multiple trainings? Do people care about the convergence of that loss too? Basically, I assume in many of the neural networks, the optimization algorithm will be very sensitive to initialization, which means the loss across epochs of a training procedure initialized with parameter set $\theta_0$ will not converge to the same loss that epochs of training procedure initialized with parameter set $\gamma_0$ converged.

Comment: @user3639557 usually with proper initialization, the loss across different training attempts will be only negligibly different.

Answer (score 0):

Putting it in more simple terms. In the black box of the neural network, we don't know the optimum value of the number of epochs. So we have to experiment on the number of epochs. And while doing that when is no convergence of loss( Loss is not decreasing much or stabilizing), that means we are getting to the correct number of the epoch.